# Froxlor mysql 1048 access denied

Tags: mysql

Since a user created another mysql database in Froxlor, I'm getting this error when trying to manage databases in froxlor (I haven't changed the root password or anything):

[image]

```
A database error occured
SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

#0 /var/www/froxlor/lib/classes/database/class.Database.php(279): PDO->__construct('mysql:host=127....', 'root', 'DB_ROOT_PWD', Array)
#1 /var/www/froxlor/lib/classes/database/class.Database.php(145): Database::getDB()
#2 /var/www/froxlor/customer_mysql.php(25): Database::needSqlData()
#3 {main}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had to change the mysql-host in the config from 127.0.0.1 to localhost

Comment: Which file did you changed? I have the same problem

Comment: The file is located in /var/www/froxlor/lib/userdata.inc.php by default.